# How to pass a variable from Class to another Class?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, python-class

I am using Kivy and Kivymd. I have a problem with passing a variable between `class Admin` and `class EditArticle`. I need to pass `my_string` from Admin to EditArticle. I am trying to do this, but getting an empty string.
So,  in `class Admin` I have `my_string`. Then, in a method `edit_article` of `class Admin` i am setting value 'some text' for `my_string`. Then I am trying to get it in the method `edit` of  `class EditArticle`. But it is empty all the time. I really cannot figure it out.

1. If you run my code you will click on top menu `admin`.
2. Then to click on any `mdchip`.
3. Then to click on etit button in dialog window.
4. Then to click on button to get `my_string` (but it always empty).

This is my App.py

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.chip import MDChip
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (600, 853)
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RectangularElevationBehavior
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class AdminFooter(ThemableBehavior, RectangularElevationBehavior, MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.md_bg_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color

class ToolbarBack(ThemableBehavior, RectangularElevationBehavior, MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class CustomToolbar(ThemableBehavior, RectangularElevationBehavior, MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.md_bg_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color

        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_menu, 1)

    def create_menu(self, i):
        self.items = ['admin', 'settings']
        menu_items = [{"text":  f"{i}"} for i in self.items]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.button_2, items=menu_items, width_mult=4, callback=self.get_item
        )

    def get_item(self, instance):
        self.menu.dismiss()
        App.get_running_app().window_manager.current = instance.text

class Content(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Admin(Screen):

    dialog_get_article = None

    my_string = StringProperty() # My string

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_article(self, instance,*args): 
        self.dialog_get_article = MDDialog(
            title="Click the EDIT",
            buttons=[
                MDFlatButton(
                    text="EDIT",
                    on_release = self.edit_article
                ),
            ],
        )
        self.dialog_get_article.open()

    def edit_article(self, instance):
        self.my_string = 'some text' # set value
        App.get_running_app().window_manager.current = 'edit-article'
        self.dialog_get_article.dismiss()

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        data = [
            {'id': 1, 'title': 'Arcicle 1', 'body': 'body of Article 1'},
            {'id': 2, 'title': 'Arcicle 2', 'body': 'body of Article 2'},
            {'id': 3, 'title': 'Arcicle 3', 'body': 'body of Article 3'}
        ]
        for x in data:
            chip = BlogChip(id=x.get('id'), title=x.get('title'), body=x.get('body'))
            self.ids.box.add_widget(chip)

class EditArticle(Screen):

    var = StringProperty()

    def edit(self, instance):
        print(self.var, ' << it is goingt to be <my_string> from Admin')

class UserSettings(Screen):
    pass

class BlogChip(MDChip):

    get_admin = Admin()

    id = NumericProperty()
    title = StringProperty()
    body = StringProperty()

class BlogCard(MDCard):
    pass

class Detail(Screen):
    pass

class ResultSearch(Screen):
    pass

class Container(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_cards)

    def create_cards(self, i):
        pass

class App(MDApp):

    def callback(self):
        self.window_manager.current = 'container'

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Indigo'
        self.window_manager = WindowManager()
        return self.window_manager

App().run()
```

My app.kv

```
 <WindowManager>
    Container:
        id: scr_1
        name: 'container'
    Detail:
        id: scr_2
        name: 'detail'

    Admin:
        id: scr_3
        name: 'admin'
    EditArticle:
        id: scr_4
        name: 'edit-article'
        var: scr_3.my_string # <---------

    ResultSearch:
        id: scr_5
        name: 'result-search'
    UserSettings:
        id: scr_6
        name: 'settings'

<Admin>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: boxlayout_1
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
            title: 'Admin Blog'
            left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: app.callback()]]

        ScrollView:
            MDStackLayout:
                adaptive_height: True
                padding: 10
                spacing: dp(5)
                id: box

<EditArticle>
    MDToolbar:
        title: 'Admin Blog'
    MDLabel:
        text: str(root.var)
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'click me to see a variable in console'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: root.edit(root)

<MyToolbar@CustomToolbar>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.theme_cls.standard_increment
    padding: "25dp"
    spacing: "12dp"

    MDLabel:
        id: label
        text: 'Blog'
        font_style: 'H6'
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: 1,1,1,1

    Widget:

    MDIconButton:
        id: button_2
        icon: "dots-vertical"
        pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: 1,1,1,1
        on_release: root.menu.open()

<Container>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MyToolbar:
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Go To menu (dot-vertical/admin'
            halign: 'center'

<BlogCard>

<Detail>:

<BlogChip>
    label: root.title
    icon: ''
    callback: root.get_admin.get_article
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Root Cause:

In your app, there are two instances of `class Admin` instantiated.

This first instance was instantiated in the kv file when you instantiated the root, `WindowManager()` in the `build` method.

### Snippets:

```
<WindowManager>:
    ...

    Admin:
        id: scr_3
        name: 'admin'
    ...
```

The second instance was instantiated in the `class BlogChip`.

### Snippets:

```
class BlogChip(MDChip):
    get_admin = Admin()
    ...
```

The class attribute, `my_string` was updated in the second instance of `class Admin`.
But the screen is referencing the instance instantiated by the root. Therefore, the app displayed empty string.

## Solution:

The solution requires changes to the kv and python files.

### kv file:

Replace
`callback: root.get_admin.get_article`
with
`callback: app.root.ids.scr_3.get_article`

#### Snippets:

```
<BlogChip>
    label: root.title
    icon: ''
    callback: app.root.ids.scr_3.get_article
```

### Python file:

1. Remove `get_admin = Admin()` in `class BlogChip(MDChip):`

#### Snippets:

```
class BlogChip(MDChip):
    id = NumericProperty()
    title = StringProperty()
    body = StringProperty()
```

2. In method, `edit()` initialize class attribute, `var`

#### Snippets:

```
class EditArticle(Screen):
    var = StringProperty()

    def edit(self, instance):
        # Each screen has by default a property manager that 
        # gives you the instance of the ScreenManager used.
        self.var = self.manager.ids.scr_3.my_string
        print(self.var, ' << it is going to be <my_string> from Admin')
```

## Output:

[image]

Comment: Good eye, ikolim.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you are doing in your code?

Why don't you look at directly `Admin.my_string` inside your `EditArticle class`?

If this does not work, did you try to create a `getter` for your `my_string` attribute?
I apologize, I do not know how `StringProperty` works... however can't you do something like the following in the `Agent class`?

```
def get_my_string():
    return my_string.value()
```

Then you just call `Agent.get_my_string()` in your `EditArticle` class.

Comment: It is not working for me. It works if I set in 
`class Admin(Screen):`
  `my_string = StringProperty('hello world')`

Comment: Ok, unfortunately I am not used to StringProperty, aren't there setter/getter with this class than you can use?

Answer (score 0):

This is solution of my question.
I have to add `EditArticle.my_string = self.my_string` to `class Admin` something like this:

```
def edit_article(self, instance):
    EditArticle.my_string = self.my_string
    App.get_running_app().window_manager.current = 'edit-article'
    self.dialog_get_article.dismiss()
```

After this I can get it in `class EditArticle()`